# Can you join by columns with aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to join by aggregate functions?

Let's say we have in the main query:

```
Select MIN(id) as MINID, product AS PRODUCT, SUB.produkt_name, SUB.product_type
FROM log_table
GROUP BY PRODUCT, SUB.produkt_name, SUB.product_type
```

And I'm joining a subquery with all the info about products:

JOIN (some subquery) SUB ON LOG_TABLE.MINID=SUB.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
select * from
(
Select MIN(id) as MINID, product AS PRODUCT, SUB.produkt_name, SUB.product_type
FROM log_table
GROUP BY PRODUCT, SUB.produkt_name, SUB.product_type
)A JOIN (some subquery) SUB ON A.MINID=SUB.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the aggregation *before* the `JOIN`.

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT l.MINID, l.product AS PRODUCT, SUB.produkt_name, SUB.product_type
FROM (some subquery
     ) SUB JOIN
     (SELECT l.PRODUCT, MIN(l.id) as MINID
      FROM log_table l
      GROUP BY l.PRODUCT
     ) l
     ON l.MINID = SUB.ID
GROUP BY l.PRODUCT, SUB.produkt_name, SUB.product_type
```